# Oracle DB 11gR2 netca installation failing

Tags: oracle, clustering, installation

I am getting below error when I run `netca` from command line

```
cmd: /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/db_1/bin/netca /silent /responsefile=/oracle_binaries/database/response/netca.rsp

[main] [ 2013-05-17 10:52:47.975 IST ] [CmdlineArgs.parseLogParam:290]  Parsing /log argument...
[main] [ 2013-05-17 10:52:47.976 IST ] [CmdlineArgs.parseLogParam:345]  Returning Log File = null
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
        at oracle.net.ca.CmdlineArgs.parseArgs(CmdlineArgs.java:416)
        at oracle.net.ca.InitialSetup.<init>(NetCA.java:3969)
        at oracle.net.ca.NetCA.main(NetCA.java:405)
```

Comment: Since you've found the solution I wonder if you could accept your own answer so that it isn't touched by the Community account on a regular basis and therefore doesn't appear on the site's main page. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from below thread solved my problem

https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2208254

apparently '=' is not needed in responsefile argument in netca cmd

```
/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/db_1/bin/netca /silent /responsefile /oracle_binaries/database/response/netca.rsp
```